# Good way to return on locked mutex in go

Tags: go

Following problem:
I have a function that only should allow one caller to execute.
If someone tries to call the function and it is already busy the second caller should immediatly return with an error.

I tried the following:

**1. Use a mutex**

Would be pretty easy. But the problem is, you cannot check if a mutex is locked. You can only block on it. Therefore it does not work

**2. Wait on a channel**

```
var canExec = make(chan bool, 1)

func init() {
    canExec <- true
}

func onlyOne() error {
    select {
    case <-canExec:
    default:
        return errors.New("already busy")
    }

    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("done")
        canExec <- true
    }()

    // do stuff

}
```

What I don't like here:

- looks really messi
- if easy to mistakenly block on the channel / mistakenly write to the channel

**3. Mixture of mutex and shared state**

```
var open = true

var myMutex *sync.Mutex

func canExec() bool {
    myMutex.Lock()
    defer myMutex.Unlock()

    if open {
        open = false
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func endExec() {
    myMutex.Lock()
    defer myMutex.Unlock()

    open = true
}

func onlyOne() error {
    if !canExec() {
        return errors.New("busy")
    }
    defer endExec()

    // do stuff

    return nil
}
```

I don't like this either. Using a shard variable with mutex is not that nice.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a semaphore for this (`go get golang.org/x/sync/semaphore`)

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/sync/semaphore"
)

var sem = semaphore.NewWeighted(1)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if err := onlyOne(); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
        }()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func onlyOne() error {
    if !sem.TryAcquire(1) {
        return errors.New("busy")
    }
    defer sem.Release(1)
    fmt.Println("working")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 37):

I'll throw my preference out there - use the [atomic package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic).

```
var (
    locker    uint32
    errLocked = errors.New("Locked out buddy")
)

func OneAtATime(d time.Duration) error {
    if !atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&locker, 0, 1) { // <-----------------------------
        return errLocked                             //   All logic in these         |
    }                                                //   four lines                 |
    defer atomic.StoreUint32(&locker, 0)             // <-----------------------------

    // logic here, but we will sleep
    time.Sleep(d)

    return nil
}
```

The idea is pretty simple.  Set the initial value to 0 (0 value of uint32).  The first thing you do in the function is check if the value of `locker` is currently 0 and if so it changes it to 1.  It does all of this atomically.  If it fails simply return an error (or however else you like to handle a locked state).  If successful, you immediately defer replacing the value (now 1) with 0.  You don't have to use defer obviously, but failing to set the value back to 0 before returning would leave you in a state where the function could no longer be run.

After you do those 4 lines of setup, you do whatever you would normally.

https://play.golang.org/p/riryVJM4Qf

You can make things a little nicer if desired by using named values for your states.

```
const (
    stateUnlocked uint32 = iota
    stateLocked
)

var (
    locker    = stateUnlocked
    errLocked = errors.New("Locked out buddy")
)

func OneAtATime(d time.Duration) error {
    if !atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&locker, stateUnlocked, stateLocked) {
        return errLocked
    }
    defer atomic.StoreUint32(&locker, stateUnlocked)

    // logic here, but we will sleep
    time.Sleep(d)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: It looks really promising. But does it actually lock? I wanted to use it as kind of tryLock mechanism. But when I follow this solution with my code, writing to map, in ```// logic here, but we will sleep``` section I got concurrent map write. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4):

You could use standard channel approach with select statement.

```
var (
    ch = make(chan bool)
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i < 100 {
        i++
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            err := onlyOne()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Ok")
            }
        }()
        go func() {
            ch <- true
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}


func onlyOne() error {
    select {
    case <-ch:
        // do stuff
        return nil
    default:
        return errors.New("Busy")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want a function to be executed exactly once or once at given time? In former case take a look at https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once.

If you want once at a time solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// OnceAtATime protects function from being executed simultaneously.
// Example:
//    func myFunc() { time.Sleep(10*time.Second) }
//    func main() {
//        once := OnceAtATime{}
//        once.Do(myFunc)
//        once.Do(myFunc) // not executed
//    }
type OnceAtATime struct {
    m        sync.Mutex
    executed bool
}

func (o *OnceAtATime) Do(f func()) {
    o.m.Lock()
    if o.executed {
        o.m.Unlock()
        return
    }
    o.executed = true
    o.m.Unlock()
    f()
    o.m.Lock()
    o.executed = false
    o.m.Unlock()
}

// Proof of concept
func f(m int, done chan<- struct{}) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %d\n", m, i)
        time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    close(done)
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    once := OnceAtATime{}

    go once.Do(func() { f(1, done) })
    go once.Do(func() { f(2, done) })
    <-done
    done = make(chan struct{})
    go once.Do(func() { f(3, done) })
    <-done

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nZcEcWAgKp

Answer (score 4):

> But the problem is, you cannot check if a mutex is locked. You can only block on it. Therefore it does not work

With possible Go 1.18 (Q1 2022), you will be able to test if a mutex is locked... *without* blocking on it.

See (as [mentioned by Go 101](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1400813397508202500)) the [issue 45435](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45435) from [Tye McQueen](https://github.com/TyeMcQueen) :

> ### `sync`: add `Mutex.TryLock`

This is followed by [CL 319769](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/319769/), with the caveat:

> Use of these functions is almost (but not) always a bad idea.
>
> Very rarely they are necessary, and third-party implementations (using a mutex and an atomic word, say) cannot integrate as well with the race detector as implementations in package sync itself.

[The objections](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45435#issuecomment-832910477) (since retracted) were:

> Locks are for protecting invariants.
> If the lock is held by someone else, there is nothing you can say about the invariant.
>
> `TryLock` encourages imprecise thinking about locks; it encourages making assumptions about the invariants that may or may not be true.
> That ends up being its own source of races.
>
> Thinking more about this, there is one important benefit to building `TryLock` into `Mutex`, compared to a wrapper:
> failed `TryLock` calls wouldn't create spurious happens-before edges to confuse the race detector.

And:

> A channel-based implementation is possible, but performs poorly in comparison.
> There's a reason we have `sync.Mutex` rather than just using channel for locking.

Comment: Does exactly what I (and OP) wanted, but reading the objections, I am unsure if I should use it or not

Comment: @VivekSethi As long as you are using `TryLock`  for scenarios where you need to check a lock's status without blocking, you should be OK. Make sure that `TryLock` does not lead to complex and hard-to-follow locking logic.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using it. `TryLock` would end up locking the mutex if it was unlocked. It would have been convenient to just get the lock status, but I understand it would not be possible (without using another lock?) when multiple go routines are at play.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following generic solution for that:

Works for me, or do you see any problem with that?

```
import (
 "sync"
)

const (
    ONLYONECALLER_LOCK = "onlyonecaller"
    ANOTHER_LOCK = "onlyonecaller"
)

var locks = map[string]bool{}

var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}

func Lock(lock string) bool {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()

    locked, ok := locks[lock]
    if !ok {
        locks[lock] = true
        return true
    }

    if locked {
        return false
    }

    locks[lock] = true
    return true
}

func IsLocked(lock string) bool {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()

    locked, ok := locks[lock]
    if !ok {
        return false
    }

    return locked
}

func Unlock(lock string) {
    mutex.Lock()
    defer mutex.Unlock()

    locked, ok := locks[lock]
    if !ok {
        return
    }

    if !locked {
        return
    }

    locks[lock] = false
}
```

see: https://play.golang.org/p/vUUsHcT3L-

Answer (score 0):

How about this package: https://github.com/viney-shih/go-lock . It use **channel** and **semaphore** ([golang.org/x/sync/semaphore](https://github.com/golang/sync/blob/master/semaphore/semaphore.go)) to solve your problem.

`go-lock` implements `TryLock`, `TryLockWithTimeout` and `TryLockWithContext` functions in addition to Lock and Unlock. It provides flexibility to control the resources.

Examples:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "context"

    lock "github.com/viney-shih/go-lock"
)

func main() {
    casMut := lock.NewCASMutex()

    casMut.Lock()
    defer casMut.Unlock()

    // TryLock without blocking
    fmt.Println("Return", casMut.TryLock()) // Return false

    // TryLockWithTimeout without blocking
    fmt.Println("Return", casMut.TryLockWithTimeout(50*time.Millisecond)) // Return false

    // TryLockWithContext without blocking
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 50*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    fmt.Println("Return", casMut.TryLockWithContext(ctx)) // Return false


    // Output:
    // Return false
    // Return false
    // Return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets keep it simple:

```
    package main
    
    import (
     "fmt"
     "time"
     "golang.org/x/sync/semaphore"
    )

    var sem *semaphore.NewWeighted(1)

    func init() {
      sem = emaphore.NewWeighted(1)
    }

    func doSomething() {
      if !sem.TryAcquire(1) {
        return errors.New("I'm busy")
      }
      defer sem.Release(1)
      fmt.Println("I'm doing my work right now, then I'll take a nap")
      time.Sleep(10)
    }

    func main() {
      go func() {
        doSomething()
      }()
    }
```